# Intel fortran support in Xcode 4

Tags: macos, fortran, xcode4, intel

I tried to install Intel Fortran 11 with Xcode 4. It does not work. Is there any version which works with Xcode 4?

Comment: FORTRAN is still the most efficient of all programming languages. It can be an old stuff. But when you come to the point of efficiency, nothing can beat FORTRAN.

Comment: Personally I hate FORTRAN. But what to do if you have no other option. For our research, we have to use a code which has been written in 70s. No one has the drive to port it to C/C++. Because that will not be a new work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Intel Fortran person reports that support for Xcode 4 is in progress.  http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=81338&o=a&s=lr